# ListView Column Width Auto

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listview, autosize

I wrote code in XAML - WPF Browser Application - Page , just one `Listview` and one `button` to add new data to the `listview` (from other file), I am trying to make the first column auto size itself when the button is pushed, I am using Visual Studio c# 2010.

I've used the following method in the code behind, but `AutoResizeColumns` won't be recognized and gives an error.

Unfortunately, none of the previously suggested solutions worked with me.

The Code Behind

```
public partial class Page1 : Page, INotifyPropertyChanged
{

    public Page1()
    {

        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = new Page1Model();

    }

    private void TestListe_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void Button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)

   {
        TestListe1.AutoResizeColumns(ColumnHeaderAutoResizeStyle.ColumnContent);
   }

}
```

XAML

```
<Grid>

    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="3*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <ListView Name="TestListe1"   Margin="68,22,421,8"  FontSize="12"  >

        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridView.Columns>
                      <GridViewColumn Width="auto">                                <GridViewColumn.HeaderTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <TextBlock Text="ST1" Margin="10,0,10,1"/>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn.HeaderTemplate>
                        <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding One}" />
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn>

                                        </GridView.Columns>
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
   </ListView>

    <Button Name="Button1" Grid.Row="1" Height="27" Width="95" Margin="262,24,444,74"  Click="Button1_Click" />

</Grid>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[`AutoResizeColumns`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.autoresizecolumns.aspx) is from the namespace `System.Windows.Forms`. I'm not sure if that will work with WPF or not.  But you can set the width of the column to `NAN` to make it resize

In your `XAML` if you name your GridView as follows:

```
<GridView x:Name="dataGridView">
```

Then you could resize all columns with this

```
 foreach (GridViewColumn c in dataGridView.Columns)
 {
     c.Width = 0; //set it to no width
     c.Width = double.NaN; //resize it automatically
 }
```

Comment: Great! Thanks. And it worked like this either: <GridViewColumn Width="NaN">